# Permission denied when tring to download file from SFTP server using cURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl, sftp

I'm trying to shorten the time needed to download a file from SFTP by integrating SFTP and cURL.

My codes are as below:

```
$host = "192.168.1.1";
$username = "testuser";
$password = "testpass";
$fn = 'testfile.zip';
$remote = "sftp://".$username.":".$password ."@".$host.":22/home/testfolder/saleskits/".$fn;

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $remote); #input
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);
curl_exec($curl);
if (!curl_errno($curl)) {
    $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
    echo 'Took ', $info['total_time'], ' seconds to send a request to ', $info['url'], "\n";
}
else{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
}
curl_close($curl);
```

and the output is "Curl error: Could not open remote file for reading: Permission denied ". How can I get passed the permission or change the permission of the file?

Comment: looks like user-name\password are wrong

Comment: but it didn't show authentication failure. I tried setting the wrong password, an error "Authentication failed" was shown.

Comment: Can you download the file using any other (even GUI) SFTP client?

Comment: @nogad Unlikely. That would be *"authentication failed"*, not *"permission denied"*.

Comment: I wish I can, but the requirement of the task is to download the file from SFTP in php. I did try phpseclib, but the speed is way too slow.

Comment: I'm not asking you to change the implementation, I'm asking you, if it is even possible to download the file. Or if you indeed do not have permissions to download it. If the latter, you do not have a programming question.

Comment: oops, sorry for misunderstanding your words. I did try to download the file by using phpseclib and I managed to download the file. This error only happened when i use cURL. So is this a programming question?

Comment: Well for the phpseclib approach you could provide the maintainer of that package with the info he requested: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/1035#issuecomment-248006193 Might be possible to tweak the performance of phpseclib based on the info you provide..

Answer (score 0):

The `cURL` URL does not contain port according to documentation. Also SFTP defaults to 22 so it is bogus in your example. You can use:

```
$remote = "sftp://".$username.":".$password ."@".$host."/home/testfolder/saleskits/".$fn;
```

Comment: tried removing the port, but it's still showing permission denied.